# How to detect if fetch cursor returned no value?

Tags: oracle, if-statement, cursor

I have this:

```
declare
  toStoreA varchar2(10);
  toStoreB varchar2(10);
  toStoreC varchar2(10);

  cursor c1 is
    select a, b, c
    from table1
    where login = 'myLogin';
begin
  open  c1;
  fetch c1 into toStoreA,
                toStoreB,
                toStoreC
  close c1;

  if toStoreB = NULL then
    dbms_output.put_line('OK, we are in if, toStoreB is null');
  end if;

  dbms_output.put_line('toStoreA:' || toStoreA || '_');
  dbms_output.put_line('toStoreB:' || toStoreB || '_');
  dbms_output.put_line('toStoreC:' || toStoreC || '_');
end;
```

My target is to detect if `fetch cursor` returned no value.

If I will query my sql statement in sql window I will get this:

```
> select a, b, c from table1 where login = 'myLogin';
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ some val +               +               +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

This is what I get in DBMS Output window:

```
toStoreA:some val_
toStoreB:_ 
toStoreC:_
```

As you see, I don't get string `OK, we are in if, toStoreB is null` in DBMS Output. Why? Well, obvious if is not passed. The question is how to correctly check if `fetch cursor` returned `null` value (no value)?

I'd also tried `if toStoreB = '' then` but it didn't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't test for null with equality; null is never equal to (or *not* equal to) anything, including itself. And the empty string `''` is indistinguishable from null, so you can't use equality tests for that either. [See the explanation in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17118/sql_elements005.htm). You can fix the immediate problem by using [the `is null` operator](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17118/conditions008.htm) instead:

```
  if toStoreB is NULL then
```

With that change you see:

```
anonymous block completed
OK, we are in if, toStoreB is null
toStoreA:some val_
toStoreB:_
toStoreC:_
```

---

*I slightly misinterpreted the question initially, thinking you meant that you wanted to check if the fetch returned no rows, rather than that a specific column had no value; so the rest of this isn't directly relevant. If you're always expecting a single row then you can use `select into ...` instead of a named cursor; but with a cursor you can test for what was fetched more flexibly...*

That only tells you that the fetch didn't find anything if `b` cannot be null; even if you think that's the case now it isn't something you should necessarily rely on, and isn't a generic solution.

You can check whether anything was fetched with [the `%notfound' cursor attribute](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e17126/cursor_attribute.htm):

```
  open  c1;
    fetch c1 into toStoreA,
                  toStoreB,
                  toStoreC;
    if c1%notfound then
      dbms_output.put_line('No row was fetched');
    end if;
  close c1;
```

Note that it has to be checked before you close the cursor, usually straight after a fetch. It will error if you try to check it after the `close`. This is often used to break out of a loop that fetches, once all data has been retrieved.

So with both changes and a modified query that finds no data, you see:

```
anonymous block completed
No row was fetched
OK, we are in if, toStoreB is null
toStoreA:_
toStoreB:_
toStoreC:_
```